# Selective updates with newly-created installation ISO

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-installation

I purchased retail boxed/full-version licenses of Windows 8.1 Pro for several new PCs that shipped with Windows 8.1 (non-Pro), but the DVDs included are 1.5 years old.  I am considering using **option 1** in [this tutorial](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/18309-windows-8-windows-8-1-iso-download-create.html) to create a new installation DVD

**Question 1**: Does Microsoft's `mediacreationtool.exe` always include the latest (security and optional) updates to Windows 8.1?

If not, I will just use the DVD included in my boxed version.

If so, there are certain updates I want to exclude [relating to user data collection](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2979054/windows-security/windows-7-8-10-now-all-collecting-user-data-for-microsoft.html).

**Question 2**: If I use the installation media created by `mediacreationtool.exe`, can I uninstall selective KB updates?

I don't want to connect a new PC to internet until it is fully patched with security updates.

**Question 3**: Where can I find update rollups to minimize the effort needed to get security up-to-date but optional patches up to the end of 2014, when I understand that Microsoft had not yet started installing the Windows 10 preparation and spyware into Windows 8.1.

Any other advice from users with similar concerns would be appreciated.

Comment: have you downloaded the .iso and determine what updates are and are not included?

Comment: @Ramhound - I haven't done that because 1) I don't know how to tell what updates are included, and 2) I was hoping to get advice from experienced users before going through hours of effort.

Comment: How about this? Goto a patched PC use the Windows 10 mediacreationtool to make an ISO or USB stick, and use that to upgrade to Windows 10 and avoid the Windows 8 monster.

Answer (score 0):

```
Beverage
Good eBook
<Setup>
md c:\win8
md c:\updates
md c:\mountw8

copy <wherever it is>\install.wim c:\win8
<Internet Explorer>
http://catalog.update.microsoft.com
<agree to plug in>
(Make sure you get the one for the correct OS and x86 or x64)
Type in the KB####### one at a time and add them to cart
When prompted for a folder browse to c:\updates
<Start Reading Book>
<Wait for download>
<Keep waiting>

dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:c:\win8\install.wim /index:1 /MountDir:c:\mountw8
<Resume Reading Book>
for /R "C:\Updates\" %i in (*.msu) do dism /image:c:\mountw8 /Add-Package /PackagePath:"%i"
<Wait>
<Wait some more>
<Keep waiting>

As long as we have the image mount lets inject some drives

(Modify the path to your needs)
(Make sure the drivers are extracted so the *.inf files are visible)
DISM.exe /Image:C:\mountw8 /Add-Driver /Driver:d:\Drivers\ /Recurse

<Resume Reading Book>

(Finalize the image)
dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:c:\mountw8 /commit

Make a bootable media disc replacing the old install.wim with this one.
```

Comment: Why is this all formatted as code?

Comment: because without it, lines are merged together that shouldn't be.  @Jamal